# TogglerBar Text Cuting

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

Does anyone know how to prevent the text from cutting when using a Togglerbar?
I would like the text to wrap instead.

For instance:

```
TogglerBar[Dynamic[x], {a ->
   Text[Style[
     "a)   Early runs of the Turing test used individuals, who were \
easily fooled by the machines used.", "Roboto", 21]],
  b ->
   Text[Style[
     "b)   Turing, whose test examines machines\[CloseCurlyQuote] \
ability to behave in a way indistinguishable from human behavior, has \
a UK law named after him.", "Roboto", 21]]
  }, Appearance -> "Vertical"]
```

[image]

Comment: I see that the "b)" text gets cut inconsistently depending on the width of the window. Weird. Anyway, you can force it to a particular width by wrapping the `Text` inside a `Panel`.

Comment: Strange... What version & OS are you using? For me (Windows 10, Mathematica 12.1), it looks like this: https://imgur.com/VWQn4yL - note how the second one is wrapped for me, while the first one is broken instead

Comment: Eliminate the `Text` wrappers. Just use the `Style`. `TogglerBar[Dynamic[x], {a -> Style["a)Early runs of the Turing test used individuals, who were easily fooled by the machines used.", "Roboto", 21], ...]

Comment: @LukasLang I'm using the same for both. It actually randomly chooses what to break. Since I have more options usually,